# To copy the content of the file between between two matches to other file

Tags: tcl

I have a file in which data is shown below:

```
Files {

string1

string2

string3
 ... 
 ...

}
```

but I want to copy content between `{` & `}` i.e `string1`, `string2` to other file both the braces are in different lines to other files.

Comment: Any attempts so far? You could make a variable that will tell whether you're inside a brace `{}` or not. If you see `{`, set the variable to 1 and as long as it's equal to 1, copy the line. When you see `}`, set it to 0 and stop copying, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since Tcl is so flexible, and that file has a Tcl-ish syntax, I'd do this:

```
proc Files {data} {set ::files_data $data}
source data_file

set fin [open other_file r]
set fout [open other_file.tmp w]
set have_string1 false
while {[gets $fin line] != -1} {
    if {$have_string1 && [string match "string2" $line]} {
        puts $fout $files_data
    }
    puts $fout $line
    if {[string match "string1" $line]} {
        set have_string1 true
    }
}
close $fin
close $fout

# next line only if you need to keep a backup of the original
file link -hard    other_file.bak other_file 
file rename -force other_file.tmp other_file
```